# Can't get map of channels to work

Tags: go, slice, channel

This might be a rookies mistake. I have a slice with a string value and a map of channels. For each string in the slice, a channel is created and a map entry is created for it, with the string as key.

I watch the channels and pass a value to one of them, which is never found.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    Test string
}

var channelsMap map[string](chan *TestStruct)

func main() {
    stringsSlice := []string{"value1"}
    channelsMap := make(map[string](chan *TestStruct))

    for _, value := range stringsSlice {
        channelsMap[value] = make(chan *TestStruct, 1)

        go watchChannel(value)
    }

    <-time.After(3 * time.Second)

    testStruct := new(TestStruct)
    testStruct.Test = "Hello!"
    channelsMap["value1"] <- testStruct

    <-time.After(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Program ended")
}

func watchChannel(channelMapKey string) {
    fmt.Println("Watching channel: " + channelMapKey)

    for channelValue := range channelsMap[channelMapKey] {
        fmt.Printf("Channel '%s' used. Passed value: '%s'\n", channelMapKey, channelValue.Test)
    }

}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/IbucTqMjdGO

Output:

```
Watching channel: value1
Program ended
```

How do I execute something when the message is fed into the channel?

Comment: channelsMap = make(map[string](chan *TestStruct)) in main function and you are done. := means declaration in short form. Doing this you shadow channelsMap declared in the global scope.

Comment: @Uvelichitel OMG :D Thanks! You should post that answer so I can choose it.

Comment: you should update your question's title to something more concise

Comment: Any suggestions, @ScottStensland ?

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your approach.

The first one is that you're redeclaring ("shadowing") the global
variable `channelsMap` in your `main` function.
(Had you completed at least some
[most basic intro to Go](https://tour.golang.org), you should have had no such problem.)

This means that your `watchChannel` (actually, all the goroutines which execute that function) read the global `channelsMap` while your `main` function writes to its local `channelsMap`.

What happens next, is as follows:

1. [The `range` statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range)
   in the `watchChannel` has a simple
   map lookup expression as its source—`channelsMap[channelMapKey]`.

   In Go, this form of [map lookup](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)
   *never fails,* but if the map has no such key (or if the map is not initialized, that is, it's `nil`), the so-called
   ["zero value"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
   of the appropriate type is returned.
2. Since the global `channelsMap` is always empty, any call to `watchChannel` performs a map lookup which always returns
   the zero value of type `chan *TestStruct`.
   The zero value for any channel is `nil`.
3. The `range` statement executed over a `nil` channel
   [produces zero iterations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range).
   In other words, the `for` loop in `watchChannel` always executes
   zero times.

The more complex problem, still, is not shadowing of the global variable but rather the complete absense of synchronization between the goroutines. You're using "sleeping" as a sort of band-aid in an attempt to perform *implicit* synchronization between goroutines
but while this does appear to be okay judged by so-called
"common sense", it's not going to work in practice for two
reasons:

- Sleeping is *always* a naïve approach to synchronization as it solely depens of the fact all the goroutines will run relatively freely and uncontended. This is far from being true in many (if not most) production settings and hence is always the reason for subtle bugs. Don't ever do that again, please.
- Nothing in the [Go memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem)
  says that waiting against wall-clock timing is considered by the runtime as establishing the order on how execution of different goroutines relate to each other.

There exist various ways to synchronize execution between goroutines. Basically they amount to sends and receives over channels and using the types provided by the `sync` package.
In your particular case the simplest approach is probably using the `sync.WaitGroup` type.

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/d-UGXVDXoTz) is what we would
have after fixing the problems explained above:
- Initialize the map variable right at the point of its
definition and not mess with it in `main`.
- Use `sync.WaitGroup` to make `main` properly wait for all
the goroutines it spawned to singal they're done:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    Test string
}

var channelsMap = make(map[string](chan *TestStruct))

func main() {
    stringsSlice := []string{"value1"}

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(len(stringsSlice))
    for _, value := range stringsSlice {
        channelsMap[value] = make(chan *TestStruct, 1)

        go watchChannel(value, &wg)
    }

    testStruct := new(TestStruct)
    testStruct.Test = "Hello!"
    channelsMap["value1"] <- testStruct

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Program ended")
}

func watchChannel(channelMapKey string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Watching channel: " + channelMapKey)

    for channelValue := range channelsMap[channelMapKey] {
        fmt.Printf("Channel '%s' used. Passed value: '%s'\n", channelMapKey, channelValue.Test)
    }

}
```

---

The next two problems with your code become apparent once we will
have fixed the former two—after you make the "watcher" goroutines
use the same map variable as the goroutine running `main`, and
make the latter properly wait for the watchers:

- There is a [data race](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong)
  over the map variable between the
  code which updates the map after the `for` loop spawning the
  watcher goroutines ended and the code which accesses this
  variable in all the watcher goroutines.
- There is a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)
  between the watcher goroutines and the main goroutine which waits for them to complete.

  The reason for the deadlock is that the watcher goroutines
  never receive any signal they have to quit processing and
  hence are stuck forever trying to read from their respective
  channels.

The ways to fix these two new problems are simple but they
might actually "break" your original idea of structuring
your code.

First, I'd remove the data race by simply making the watchers
*not access the map variable.* As you can see, each call to
`watchChannel` receives a single value to use as the key to
read a value off the shared map, and hence each watcher always
reads a single value exactly once during its run time.
The code would become much clearer if we remove this extra
map access altogether and instead pass the appropriate channel
value directly to each watcher.
A nice byproduct of this is that we do not need a global
map variable anymore.

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/ysB3h37k1d4)'s what we'll get:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    Test string
}

func main() {
    stringsSlice := []string{"value1"}
    channelsMap := make(map[string](chan *TestStruct))

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(len(stringsSlice))
    for _, value := range stringsSlice {
        channelsMap[value] = make(chan *TestStruct, 1)

        go watchChannel(value, channelsMap[value], &wg)
    }

    testStruct := new(TestStruct)
    testStruct.Test = "Hello!"
    channelsMap["value1"] <- testStruct

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Program ended")
}

func watchChannel(channelMapKey string, ch <-chan *TestStruct, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Watching channel: " + channelMapKey)

    for channelValue := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Channel '%s' used. Passed value: '%s'\n", channelMapKey, channelValue.Test)
    }

}
```

Okay, we still have the deadlock.

There are multiple approaches to solving this but they depend
on the actual circumstances, and with this toy example, any
attempt to iterate over at least a subset of them would just
muddle the waters.
Instead, let's employ the simplest one for this case: closing
a channel makes any pending receive operation on it immediately
unblock and produce the zero value for the channel's type.
For a channel being iterated over using the `range` statement
it simply means the stamement terminates without producing any
value from the channel.

In other words, let's just close all the channels to unblock
the `range` statements being run by the watcher goroutines
and then wait for these goroutines to report their completion via the wait group.

To not make the answer overly long, I also added programmatic initialization of the string slice to make the example more interesting by having multiple watchers—not just a single one—actually do useful work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    Test string
}

func main() {
    var stringsSlice []string
    channelsMap := make(map[string](chan *TestStruct))

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        stringsSlice = append(stringsSlice, fmt.Sprintf("value%d", i))
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(len(stringsSlice))
    for _, value := range stringsSlice {
        channelsMap[value] = make(chan *TestStruct, 1)

        go watchChannel(value, channelsMap[value], &wg)
    }

    for _, value := range stringsSlice {
        testStruct := new(TestStruct)
        testStruct.Test = fmt.Sprint("Hello! ", value)
        channelsMap[value] <- testStruct
    }

    for _, ch := range channelsMap {
        close(ch)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Program ended")
}

func watchChannel(channelMapKey string, ch <-chan *TestStruct, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Watching channel: " + channelMapKey)

    for channelValue := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Channel '%s' used. Passed value: '%s'\n", channelMapKey, channelValue.Test)
    }

}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/urOoixhmYkj).

---

As you can see, there are things you should actually learn
about in way more greater detail before embarking on working with
concurrency.

I'd recommend to proceed in the following order:

1. [The Go tour](https://tour.golang.org) would make you accustomed with the bare bones of concurrency.
2. [The Go Programming Language](http://www.gopl.io) has two chapters dedicated to providing the readers with a gentle introduction with tackling concurrency both using channels and the types from the `sync` package.
3. [Concurrency In Go](https://katherine.cox-buday.com/concurrency-in-go/) goes on with presenting more hard-core details of how one deals with concurrency in Go, including advanced topics approaching the real-world problems concurrent programs face in production—such as ways to rate-limit incoming requests.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive answer. Just for info: I only used the "sleeps" because I wanted to make sure the prototype worked similarly to my actual code. Having a signal sent in a later time so i could ask about the problem I was having.

Comment: I do not want to sound harsh, but let me have this straight: sleeps should never ever be used for anything in Go code except rare cases of implementing something like "retrying an action after a random delay" (akin to exponential backoff in Ethernet). Using sleeping for synchronization is asking for trouble—you might have evaded possible problems in this particular case but in another it will bite you in the neck. Just structure your concurrent code correctly up front, and there will never be any reasons for sleeping. This is a crucial skill to gain.

Comment: As I said, I only used them to write this little example prototype so the main problem could be reproduced easily. I'll keep your advice in mind, thank you!

Comment: My message seems to not coming across. To make it extra clear, it's absolutely possible for any number (including all) of your "waiter" goroutines to not even begin executing by the time the second calls to `time.After` terminates. Your common sense tells you it's impossible, but anyone working with Go in production sooner or later will see that it _is_ possible. So my point is not to solicit any sort of excuse from you, but rather is to make you (and whoever happening to read this thread) unlearn this approach completely. I'm not _blaming_ you for anything, so there's no point in defending.

Answer (score 0):

The shadowing in main of channelsMap mentioned above was a critical bug, but aside from that, the program was playing "Russian roulette" with the calls to time.After so that main wouldn't finish before the watcher goroutines did. This is unstable and unreliable, so I recommend the following approach using a channel to signal when all watcher goroutines are done:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    Test string
}

var channelsMap map[string](chan *TestStruct)

func main() {
    stringsSlice := []string{"value1", "value2", "value3"}
    structsSlice := []TestStruct{
        {"Hello1"},
        {"Hello2"},
        {"Hello3"},
    }
    channelsMap = make(map[string](chan *TestStruct))
    // Signal channel to wait for watcher goroutines.
    done := make(chan struct{})

    for _, s := range stringsSlice {
        channelsMap[s] = make(chan *TestStruct)
        // Give watcher goroutines the signal channel.
        go watchChannel(s, done)
    }

    for _, ts := range structsSlice {
        for _, s := range stringsSlice {
            channelsMap[s] <- &ts
        }
    }

    // Close the channels so watcher goroutines can finish.
    for _, s := range stringsSlice {
        close(channelsMap[s])
    }

    // Wait for all watcher goroutines to finish.
    for range stringsSlice {
        <-done
    }
    // Now we're really done!
    fmt.Println("Program ended")
}

func watchChannel(channelMapKey string, done chan<- struct{}) {
    fmt.Println("Watching channel: " + channelMapKey)
    for channelValue := range channelsMap[channelMapKey] {
        fmt.Printf("Channel '%s' used. Passed value: '%s'\n", channelMapKey, channelValue.Test)
    }
    done <- struct{}{}
}
```

(Go Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/eP57Ru44-NW)

Of importance is the use of the done channel to let watcher goroutines signal that they're finished to main. Another critical part is the closing of the channels once you're done with them. If you don't close them, the range loops in the watcher goroutines will never end, waiting forever. Once you close the channel, the range loop exits and the watcher goruoutine can send on the done channel, signaling that it has finished working.

Finally, back in main, you have to receive on the done channel once for each watcher goroutine you created. Since the number of watcher goroutines is equal to the number of items in stringsSlice, you simply range over stringsSlice to receive the correct amount of times from the done channel. Once that's finished, the main function can exit with a guarantee that all watchers have finished.